# Facebook - TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio

Please let me know if you need to see anything else.

I added Facebook to my project. I am using Android studio. My error after build is this:

> ```
>  Execution failed for task ':king:dexDebug'.
> ```
>
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Users/chad.bingham/Documents/sdk/build-tools/19.0.1/dx --dex --output /Users/chad.bingham/Development/Android/KingoftheCard/king/build/libs/king-debug.dex /Users/chad.bingham/Development/Android/KingoftheCard/king/build/classes/debug /Users/chad.bingham/Development/Android/KingoftheCard/king/build/dependency-cache/debug /Users/chad.bingham/Development/Android/KingoftheCard/king/build/pre-dexed/debug/android-support-v4-e2aa3ac97d06a6c260b9e7a8e8b5b67bedf586a1.jar /Users/chad.bingham/Development/Android/KingoftheCard/king/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-77e2a94f0954846e61795cd81b4927c70f7ddd34.jar /Users/chad.bingham/Development/Android/KingoftheCard/king/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-dca0b79a4b1578f641fd0837fba5826a05b82bf3.jar /Users/chad.bingham/Development/Android/KingoftheCard/king/build/pre-dexed/debug/Parse-1.3.9-9d5a3b199ec45c97e80ea5dccd8d494dd1434a38.jar /Users/chad.bingham/Development/Android/KingoftheCard/king/build/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-19.0.0-22fbcf9fc92c2104fe5528ed1038f864952f9cf3.jar
>     Error Code:
>       2
>     Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

### EDIT

**Project build.gradle**

```
 buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

android {
     compileSdkVersion 19
     buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

   defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
       versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
 }

dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
   compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.9.jar')
   compile project(':libraries:facebook')
 }
```

**Facebook build.gradle**

```
 buildscript {
 repositories {
     maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
  }
   dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.0+'
    }
 }

 apply plugin: 'android-library'

 dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
 }

 android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
      targetSdkVersion 19
  }

  sourceSets {
      main {
          manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
          java.srcDirs = ['src']
           resources.srcDirs = ['src']
           res.srcDirs = ['res']
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Check your support libraries that are included. You should only include one.

Comment: No, he is wrong..if you include the appcomtv7 it will have both the v7appcompat and supportv4 jars added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Found solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974382/gradle-build-failure-when-trying-to-use-facebook-sdk?rq=1). Originally it didnt work, so I had to do File > Invalidate Caches / Restart