# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: Multiple dex files define

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

I've added a third lib to my android project. And when I pack it by ant, some errors occur:

```
 [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
   [dx] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:593)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:551)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:532)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:169)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:187)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I've checked this problem and found this:[Android Studio - UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception)
But my eclipse project does not have a build.gradle file, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Where you finding build.gradle file ?

Comment: @Haresh In my project folder

Comment: Have you used any library project for you project like facebook sdk ?

Comment: @Haresh Yes, I've added an third sdk.

Comment: can you please check libs folder to third sdk and make sure your project contain only those library which can not be contain by other third sdk.

Comment: @Haresh I've checked the .jar I added. There is a android-support-v4.jar, and my project also have one. But I cannot delete mine because I have to commit to svn server. Any advice?

Comment: You have to remove from your project and what is problem if you remove from your project and svn ?

Comment: Duplicate?: [Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7870265/456814).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be caused by both your app project and the library project bringing the android-support-v4 jar. If the library project is already bringing this jar as dependency then you'll need to exclude it from your app project classpath.