# Execution failed for task ':tweetLanes:dexDebug'

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio to run this code, get the error:
*Error:Execution failed for task ':tweetLanes:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2*

2 days couldn't solve the problem. Tried everything I can find online, nothing helped and always the same error.

Here is the build.gradle :

*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':tLSocialNetLib')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile files('libs/basic-http-client-android-0.88.jar')
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v4_3_0_sdkonly.jar')
    compile files('libs/dashclock-api-r1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/prime-0.6.1.jar')
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.tweetlanes.android"
    android:versionCode="57"
    android:versionName="1.4.1">

    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="17"
        android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_launcher_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.App"
        tools:replace="label">
         >

        <activity
            android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.BootActivity"
            >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="twitter.com" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mobile.twitter.com" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="twitter.com" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="mobile.twitter.com"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.twitter.com" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.mobile.twitter.com" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.twitter.com" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mobile.twitter.com"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="alpha.app.net"  />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="alpha.app.net"  />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.alpha.app.net"  />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.alpha.app.net"  />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.NewAccountActivity"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:scheme="com.tweetlanes.android.core.newaccount" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.HomeActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"
            >

            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
               <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.ProfileActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:scheme="com.tweetlanes.android.core.profile" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.SearchActivity"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:scheme="com.tweetlanes.android.core.search" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.TweetSpotlightActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_tweet_spotlight_activity_name"
            >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.ImageViewActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <data android:scheme="com.tweetlanes.android.core.mediaview" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.TutorialActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TweetLanes.Light"
            android:label="@string/tutorial_title"
            >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.DirectMessageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TweetLanes.Light"
            >
        </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.SettingsActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_settings">
        </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.TwitterAuthActivity"
             android:theme="@style/Theme.TweetLanes.Light"
             android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="tweetlanes-auth-callback:///" android:host="callback" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.AppDotNetAuthActivity"
             android:theme="@style/Theme.TweetLanes.Light"
             android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="appdotnet-auth-callback:///" android:host="callback" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.AlarmReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.DeleteNotificationsReceiver" />

        <receiver
                android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.view.DeviceBootReciever"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="true"
                android:label="StartDeviceAlerts">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

         <service
            android:name="com.tweetlanes.android.core.dashclock.TweetLanesExtension"
            android:label="@string/extension_title"
            android:permission="com.google.android.apps.dashclock.permission.READ_EXTENSION_DATA" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.dashclock.Extension" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="protocolVersion"
                android:value="1" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="description"
                android:value="@string/extension_description" />
        </service>

        <!-- Start of Crittercism.com Code -->
        <activity android:name="com.crittercism.NewFeedbackSpringboardActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.crittercism.NewFeedbackIssueListActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.crittercism.NewFeedbackQuestionListActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.crittercism.NewFeedbackItemDetailsActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.crittercism.NewFeedbackCreateActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.crittercism.NotificationActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <!-- End of Crittercism.com Code -->



    </application>



</manifest>
```

Please help..

Answer (score 9):

Your app classes maybe contain over 65K methods.

Add configurations into your build.gradle,

```
  defaultConfig {
        ...
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
  }

 dependencies {
       ...
       compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
 }
```

In your manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element,

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

***Or,***
If your app uses extends the Application class, you can override the `attachBaseContext()` method and call `MultiDex.install(this)` to enable multidex. For more information, see the MultiDexApplication reference documentation.

See [Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)

Answer (score 1):

If you have support-v4 and support-v7 in build.gradle then add this line into your build.gradle at top after plugin declaration.

`configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}`

[Also read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception)