# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

The application was able to execute before updating my android studio,this is the error I am getting:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: 
    Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished 
    with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have support-v4 and support-v7 (with different version) in build.gradle then add this line into your build.gradle at top.

`configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}`

[Also read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception)

Answer (score 4):

in my case, the

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

in my build.gradle exceeded the 65k method limit.

i changed it to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
```

to fix it (i only need maps in my application)

hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

I got this error today out of nothing, after that i tried to update every single thing available, tried to change my gradle build as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965398/gradle-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1-ic-launcher-png-error-duplicate-fi)  but none of it worked.

After hours of dispair and AS updates, a simple "clean project" and "rebuild project" worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just rebuilding project fixes the issue (Build->Rebuild Project). You can also clean project

Answer (score 1):

Do this it really help me! 
`configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}` write this inside gradle module. Hope it help!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed that adding:

`compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0@aar'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Remove google analytics V2 helps for me

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```