# Android studio Unexpected Top Level exception

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I followed the guide from this question: [Android Studio - UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception)

but it still refuses to compile correctly, I've tried looking for the duplicate entries but cannot find it, the error is as follows

> 

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\ShadowFox\Android-sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Work\SystemMonitor - version 4.0\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Work\SystemMonitor - version 4.0\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v7/app/ActionBar$Callback;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Then for my Module:app build.gradle I have

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "edu.fiu.cis.visa.systemmonitor"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile project(":libs:AndroidCommon")
}
```

and my library's build.gradle is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

 >   sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
        compile files('libs/jackson-all-1.9.11.jar')
        compile files('libs/RootTools-3.4.jar')
    }
}
```

Comment: `Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompatIcs`You seem to have conflicts in your dependencies. That message means that you have more than one definitions of this class and the system does not know which one to choose from. Please show us the `gradle.build` file

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle ?

Comment: just edit the build.grade

Comment: @Eddi3 ,it's not properly formatted.It's creating a lot confusion

Comment: how do I properly format it? I tried using the annotations in the box and then copy and paste straight from android studio console but it messes up the indentation

Comment: I have done editing,just accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The library `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` is fetched both times. Remove the first one.

You fetch the library, and then your library's `build.gradle` fetches it again

Comment: Are you sure? because I commented one out if you see it, it has the // behind it so it's commented out

Comment: Edited so no one gets confused, that's what I have now

Comment: Make sure you hit `Save` on the file in order for the filesystem to update it, and also run `gradle --refresh-dependecies` in order to clean the cache and re-fetch the dependencies.

Comment: `Ok, so in the latest version of Android Studio 0.1.3, they've added a Gradle project refresh button next to the other Android specific buttons in the toolbar. Make changes manually to the build.gradle files and settings.gradle and then click this button. It should configure and refresh your project settings based on the gradle files.` There is a button in android studio that refreshes the gradle dependencies. Find it and click it.

Comment: yea I already did that but it still giving me this compile error

Comment: wait I just restarted android studio after doing your step and it's working :D thanks

Comment: nevermind, it's still not working :/ my bad I thought it was fixed but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

try this

in the `app:build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.fiu.cis.visa.systemmonitor"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
         }
```

And put it in the app:build.gradle file

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```