# Android studio Unexpected top-level exception. Error parsing classes

Tags: android, android-studio

I know there is many of this questions, but they all not pointing to error I have. I'm NOT using Gradle, this is grandfathered project. I was working on redoing 1 activity with using Fragments. When I was done and there was no errors/etc in classes - tried to compile and got this error. Before it was running and compiling just fine. I can't find any pointers in this message in where to look. Any suggestions?

```
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:170)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:161)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:130)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: InvokeDynamic not supported
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.determineOffsets(ConstantPoolParser.java:226)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:132)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:482)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] ... 20 more
Error:Android Dex: [DMD-Android] 1 error; aborting
```

Comment: Did you check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31797022/4848308?

Comment: Nope, that is not it. I did comment most of the code I touched and it compiles now. Didn't find what exactly causing it yet. Will update later when I find out

Comment: Yep, that was it. I let studio "fix" click handler and it caused it. Now I changed framework so it doesn't happen again

Answer (score 0):

In your Gradle, please add:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```