# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes

Tags: java, android, gradle

I just added a external library,and there came the errors in Android Studio.

```
 UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)  
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
... 12 more
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
'F:\java\jdk8\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.administrator.mp3test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
   compile files('libs/javaAudioBass.jar')
}
```

The external library is a audio library in java.In the library,
**I don't delete some codes about awt,because I copy it from java library,will it cause problem?**
I want to know what is the problem with it.So confused about it.Thanks all guys..

**The most important thing is,the library use JNI,I forgot to import .so file.**
It's my first time use JNI

Comment: refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception

Comment: update your build.gradle here, Will get an idea on whats wrong

Comment: Are you using java8?

Comment: Yes,I am using java8. @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: If the .jar library got some error ,will it cause the java.lang.RuntimeException? Bty,I just add a audio library and built a blank Activity.