# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. >

Tags: android

I am getting this error when trying to run the project. Here is  my build.gradle(Module:app) help me please

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:compileLint
:lib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:lib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:checkReleaseManifest
:lib:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:lib:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:lib:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:lib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:lib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:lib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:lib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:lib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:lib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:lib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:lib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:lib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:lib:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:lib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:lib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:lib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:lib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:lib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:lib:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:lib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:lib:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:lib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:lib:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:lib:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:lib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:lib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:lib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComSquareupLeakcanaryLeakcanaryAndroid131Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareMCSKLibUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/squareup/picasso/Action$RequestWeakReference;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 1 mins 17.833 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'enter code here
    useLibrary('org.apache.http.legacy')
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.qubit.mcsk"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/crouton-1.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/systembartint-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/crouton-1.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/buzzboxSDK-0.6.5.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
    compile project(':lib')

}
apply plugin: 'announce'
```

and this my build.gradle(Module:lib)

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.2.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
}

//apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle'
```

Comment: You did not post the root cause. Above the last error trace there is the root cause. Please post this.

Comment: Could you try commenting all the lines with "compile files(..)" and run again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception)

Comment: @JorgeCasariego I have commented  all the line with 'compile files(..)' I am getting the same error      Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: @Alex this answers could help you because is the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle