# Unexpected top level exception on building APK

Tags: android, android-studio

my app worked perfectly until I tried to implement google cloud messages. it still works fine in even real devices when I click "Run" button on android studio. but whenever I tried to  build an APK file  it returns this error

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

these are the google libraries I have on my build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    AnalyticsCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
```

Comment: Why do you need `AnalyticsCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'`? Try remove it?

Comment: I changed AnalyticsCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0' to  Compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'   still getting the same error

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception?rq=1

Comment: already tried that. its not working.