# Android Studio - UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION error

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I want to add these two libraries in my `build.gradle` file, But I'm getting this error, What should i do now?

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
}
```

> error: Android Studio UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Update: Screenshot
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc5eE.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception

Comment: Sir, I am new in android development, i try to rearrange my libraries according to your link, but i am not able to do that. can you arrange these libraries here.

Comment: You have to add more details about the gradle error. Use ./gradlew assemble --info

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Please see the screenshot

Answer (score -1):

```
compile (':xyzSDK') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```