# android build-gradle error :app:dexDebug

Tags: android, build.gradle

Here is my `build.gradle` file (inside the app module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myFirtApp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

The error I get:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]:    65536
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:283)
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25743147/3020568

Comment: set this firstly compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

Comment: Please follow Deniz given url

Comment: The issue was with one of the jar files, it was a beta version which was working yesterday  but not today...  I removed it and Grable build succeeded

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26515860/2016562

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved; one of the jar files was beta version and was causing issues after two days of usage; once deleted, the app run properly.